# Azure site only works when running locally with remote database

Tags: asp.net, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a site that's running off windows azure and I have hooked up the database via a linked resource and it looks like the site should be using the database. I've also included the proper connection string in my web.config file.

When I run the website locally and use the azure database's connection string for my default connection, everything works and I've seen that updating data from my local machine is reflected in the remote database.

Whenever I try to access any page that makes database hits (ie, logging in or looking at the basic index (from scaffolded out views)), I get a 500 error. I tried turning on custom errors but the 500 error is all I get. I tried to debug it from my local machine but that didn't help at all since everything worked properly when running the site locally and connecting with the azure database.

I have also pulled down the web.config files and the web.configs on both sides are identical.

I figure that this has to do with a configuration issue, but I'm not sure what.

Is there maybe something I'd have to do with asp.net mvc 5 to make it work with windows azure? It looks like the .net framework is properly set on azure to .net 4.5. I'm guessing it has something to do with the fact that Azure just doesn't know it should be using the database supplied in the web.config.

Here are the web.config connection strings:

```
<add name="DefaultConnection" connectionString="Data Source=####.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=####_db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=####" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DefaultConnectionDeploy" connectionString="Data Source=####.database.windows.net;Initial Catalog=####_db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=####" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
<add name="DefaultConnection_DatabasePublish" connectionString="Data Source=####.database.windows.net,1433;Initial Catalog=####_db;Persist Security Info=True;User ID=####;Password=####" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
```

Comment: Can you provide any details as to what's not working?  Just saying "not working" is not enough information to make a suggestion

Comment: My apologies. Whenever I try to access any page that makes database hits (ie, logging in or looking at the basic index (from scaffolded out views)), I get a 500 error. I tried turning on custom errors but the 500 error is all I get. I tried to debug it from my local machine but that didn't help at all since everything worked properly when running the site locally and connecting with the azure database.

Comment: Please also include the type of database (Azure SQL Database vs MySQL, etc.) and if you are running on a Windows Azure Web Site or a Web Role in a Cloud Service.

Comment: It's an Azure Website with an Azure SQL Database (I think - when I go into the Azure dashboard I see it under 'Website' and I see my database under 'SQL databases')

Comment: Republish the site with CustomErrors off.  Let us know the yellow exception that you get

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per Andrew-counts' suggestion, I went and checked out my EF migrations (after pulling down the Azure web.config file using the "Replace web.config from server" option so that I had the exact copy that the server is using. I then enabled custom errors. It turns out that the pages were failing to load because of an error that stated that the table dbo.AspNetRoles already exists.

It appeared as though it was trying to run the EF migrations despite the fact that the tables already existed. To remedy this, I decided to go and wipe out my current database (I had just setup the database today so no harm doing that) and then, from the package console in visual studio, ran the Update-Database script before deploying anything to the server. When I did that, it correctly added the records inside of the dbo.__MigrationHistory table. I then checked in my changes so that the visualstudio.com build I have connected to my solution would build and deploy to Azure. The problem persisted, but what I realized was that I need to disable the automatic build + deploy that I was using and instead use the right click + publish, since doing it from the visual studio build wasn't connecting to the azure database properly (it wasn't transforming the web.config). When I used the publish from within visual studio, the site worked like a charm.

Thank you for all your help

Answer (score 0):

Windows Azure makes use of transforms to manage connection strings.  The connection strings are merged in at runtime, and can be controlled from the configure tab on the Web Site management page.  whenever you set up an Azure Database as a linked resource, it automatically configures the Azure Database server with firewall rules to allow connection from the web server, and adds a connection string.  By using this connection string, naming it the same as the string used in development, it is not necessary to modify any code prior to deployment.  If you don't set the Azure Database up as a linked resource, it is necessary to modify the firewall rules by hand, which doesn't play nicely with the scalability of Azure Websites, so it's not recommended.

Comment: I just linked the web config from my website. The normal web.config looks at the mdf file that visual studio created for me. It looks like the connection strings in the azure site are valid/correct, so that's not the issue.

Comment: Do you know if there might be any issues caused by using MVC 5/EF 6 RC/Microsoft.AspNet.Identity RC?

Comment: are you using EF Migrations on your site? Do all the tables actually exist on the server database?

Comment: Also, you want to turn Custom Errors **off** to receive real errors, turning it on is the same as the default, which is to dump an "end user friendly" 500 error.